# Mysql nested select with multiple joins with condition on join table

Tags: mysql, join, nested, where-clause

I've got a SELECT with multiple JOINS for a paginated Tableview. In general this is working for unfiltered results.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT seltable.*, 
       tbl2.name AS tbl2name, 
       tbl3.name AS tbl3name, 
       tbl4.name AS tbl4name 
FROM
       ( SELECT * FROM selecttable 
         WHERE value = 99 
         ORDER BY datetime DESC 
         LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 ) 
       AS seltable
LEFT JOIN table1 AS tbl1 ON seltable.tbl1_uid = tbl1.uid
LEFT JOIN table2 AS tbl2 ON tbl1.tbl2_uid = tbl2.uid
LEFT JOIN table3 AS tbl3 ON tbl2.tbl3_uid = tbl3.uid
LEFT JOIN table4 AS tbl4 ON tbl3.tbl4_uid = tbl4.uid;
```

Now I've got no clue how to accomplish filtering the results with a condition related to one of the join tables.

When I just set a:

```
LEFT JOIN tablex AS table ON foreign_table.tblx_uid = table.uid AND {condition}
```

this condition regards only to the 50 results of the nested SELECT.

Is there any way to achieve using WHERE clauses on the JOIN tables in this scenario?

For sample data see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad4d/2

Expected results:

- to get x team records limited to 5 team uids, where Tournament2 is one of the related tournaments for the team.

Best regards
w1ll1

Answer (score 1):

Try not controlling the pagination in that subquery, instead just use a more conventional query with a composite where clause. HOWEVER, because you are using left joins take care adding filters through the where clause that would override the outer join to produce the effect of an inner join.

```
SELECT seltable.*, 
       tbl2.name AS tbl2name, 
       tbl3.name AS tbl3name, 
       tbl4.name AS tbl4name 
FROM selecttable AS seltable
LEFT JOIN table1 AS tbl1 ON seltable.tbl1_uid = tbl1.uid
LEFT JOIN table2 AS tbl2 ON tbl1.tbl2_uid = tbl2.uid
LEFT JOIN table3 AS tbl3 ON tbl2.tbl3_uid = tbl3.uid
LEFT JOIN table4 AS tbl4 ON tbl3.tbl4_uid = tbl4.uid
WHERE seltable.value = 99 
...
ORDER BY seltable.datetime DESC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Alternatively use more subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT seltable.*, 
       tbl2.name AS tbl2name, 
       tbl3.name AS tbl3name, 
       tbl4.name AS tbl4name 
FROM
       ( SELECT * FROM selecttable 
         WHERE value = 99 
         ORDER BY datetime DESC 
         LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 ) 
       AS seltable
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT uid, name
            FROM table1
            WHERE 1=1 -- amend to suit
            ) AS tbl1 ON seltable.tbl1_uid = tbl1.uid
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT uid, name
            FROM table2
            WHERE 1=1 -- amend to suit
            ) AS tbl2 ON tbl1.tbl2_uid = tbl2.uid
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT uid, name
            FROM table3
            WHERE 1=1 -- amend to suit
            ) AS tbl3 ON tbl2.tbl3_uid = tbl3.uid
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT uid, name
            FROM table4
            WHERE 1=1 -- amend to suit
            ) AS tbl4 ON tbl3.tbl4_uid = tbl4.uid;
```

Here is another attempt, based on your sqlfiddle it appears that INNER JOINS may be used:

```
SELECT theteam.*, 
       trnmnt.name AS tournamentname, 
       cat.name AS categoryname, 
       sport.name AS sportname 
FROM ( 
  SELECT * FROM team 
  ORDER BY team.name ASC ) 
AS theteam 
INNER JOIN tournament_team AS tntm ON tntm.team_uid = theteam.uid 
INNER JOIN tournament AS trnmnt ON tntm.tournament_uid = trnmnt.uid AND trnmnt.name = 'Tournament2'
INNER JOIN category AS cat ON trnmnt.category_uid = cat.uid 
INNER JOIN sport ON cat.sport_uid = sport.uid
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
;
```

The result of that query is:

```
| UID |   NAME | TOURNAMENTNAME | CATEGORYNAME | SPORTNAME |
|-----|--------|----------------|--------------|-----------|
|   2 | Team02 |    Tournament2 |      Germany |    Soccer |
|   3 | Team03 |    Tournament2 |      Germany |    Soccer |
|   4 | Team04 |    Tournament2 |      Germany |    Soccer |
|   5 | Team05 |    Tournament2 |      Germany |    Soccer |
|   6 | Team06 |    Tournament2 |      Germany |    Soccer |
```

Comment: The problem on controlling pagination on the outside is that I need to set the LIMIT on the results of "selecttable". I've got a main table and the join tables and I need to get n Rows from the main table with all relevant Rows from the JOIN tables.

Comment: sample data and expected results - this is the most reliable way of getting what you need. trying to describe by words is very hard. Do you know how to use SQLFIDDLE? http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I added another option, this may suit you better

Comment: I just put some code on sqlfiddle to show the problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad4d/2 The result I'd like to achieve is to get x team records limitted to 5 team uids, where Tournament2 is one of the related tournaments for the team.

Comment: Fantastic help with the sqlfiddle - thank you. Now you also need to think through the expected result - don't try to describe it, just produce a matrix you would expect to get as the result (from that data). In the meantime please tale a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad4d/13 is that first query result the expected result? (and hence is the first query correct?)